# Open iTunes applications in Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ios, applications

I downloaded some apps off of iTunes and it shows up as downloaded in iTunes but doesn't show up in Launchpad or Finder. I tried opening them from iTunes or dragging them in Finder or desktop but they show up as files. How do I open and use these apps?

Answer (score 4):

iTunes apps are for iOS devices: iPhone, iPad and iPod touch.
If you want to install apps on OS X, download them from the Internet or the Mac App Store.